# Render N Tables - ReactJS, next table depends on previous table

Tags: reactjs, dynamic

Is there a way to render N amount of tables, I have to render a table based on the selection based on the previous table. I can go up to 3 tables, because there will always be at least 3 tables, but post 3, the question isnt which table data to render, but if there is even a table to actually render. I currently create the first 3 tables like so:

```
render(){
    return(
         <div>
             {this.state.renderTable1 ? (this.renderTable1Data()):(<div></div>)}
             {this.state.renderTable2 ? (this.renderTable2Data()):(<div></div>)}
             {this.state.renderTable3 ? (this.renderTable3Data()):(<div></div>)}
         </div>
    )
}
```

is there a way to do this dynamically post the 3rd selection? Im fairly new to react and am still learning, and everywhere I look for dynamically creating tables it has to do with creating the table data, and not the whether I need to create the table itself. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Or if there is something I missed when skimming the

Thank you.

Comment: What would the 3rd table render be dependent on to render?

Comment: I think this is possibly a question about your data structure and how you know which data in data set A links to the data in data set B and so on and so forth. As we know nothing about how this data is interacting its hard to say which approach would be best, but it should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to set the state to `[true, true, false]` and render the tables based on this state ? if so, you can do something like this:

```
constructor(){
  this.state = {renderTables: [true, true, false]}
}
renderTableData(index){
  // render table with index : index
}
render(){
    return(
         <div>
         {this.state.renderTables.map((renderTable, index) => (
             renderTable ? (this.renderTableData(index)) : null
         )}
         </div>
     )
}
```

you can also do it (rendering until a table) more automatically by something like:

```
let {renderTables} = this.state;
let break = false
renderTables.map((renderTable, index) => {
  if(break) return null;
  let prevRenderTable = index > 0 ? renderTables[index - 1] : true
  if (!prevRenderTable) break = true
  return (prevRenderTable ? this.renderTableData(index) : null)
})
```